# What is Android N and why does it think I'm building with it? (Android Studio 2.1.2, Windows 7)

Tags: android, android-studio

I started a new generic Android project and I'm getting an error in the Design View saying "*Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later*".

But earlier Gradle complained:  *Error:(3, 22) compileSdkVersion android-23 requires compiling with JDK 7* so I installed JDK 7 - 1.7.0_79 and that fixed the Gradle problems.   I don't really want to go to JDK 8.

So what is **Android N** ?   My understanding is that it's the "next" or "latest" version of Android, but **I don't need that** for my work.  I just need to support CalendarView and NestedScrollView.  Where am I telling it that I need "Android N", and how do I change that?

My Build.Gradle says:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ags.mycalendarviewapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is Android N ?

It is the next version of Android, API Level 24. The tasty treat is Nougat.

<sub>(no, really, that's the name)</sub>

> Where am I telling it that I need "Android N", and how do I change that?

If you are getting that in the design view, that's the version of Android that is being used for the preview. It defaults to the latest version whose SDK bits you have installed.

To change it, switch it in the bugdroid drop-down on the right side of the design view toolbar:

[image: Android Studio Design View Toolbar]